# jQueryUI Tabs: Different tab = different cookie?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have two standard jQueryUI tabs looking pretty much the same.
For the comfort, they have the cookie option added. But now when I change page from one tab to another, the same tab-index will be selected on the other page, because of the cookie.

Is it possible to assign a cookie-id to the tab function or anything alike?

The html:

```
<div id='tabs' class='ui-tabs'>  
  <ul class='ui-tabs-nav'>
    <li><a href='link'>Item</a></li>
    <li><a href='link'>Item</a></li>
    <li><a href='link'>Item</a></li>
    <li><a href='link'>Item</a></li>
    <li><a href='link'>Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $('#tabs').tabs({
    cookie: {expires: 1}, 
    spinner: '<img src=\'img/icons/loading.gif\' />', 
    load: function (e, ui) { $(ui.panel).find('.tab-loading').remove(); }, 
    select: function (e, ui) { 
      var $panel = $(ui.panel); 
      if ($panel.is(':empty')) { 
        $panel.append('<div class=\'tab-loading\' style=\'text-align: center; font-weight: bold; width: 100%\'>Loading...</div>') 
      } 
    } 
  }) 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with name :)

> Since jQuery UI 1.7 it is also possible to define the cookie name
>   being used via name property.

```
$(function() {
  $('#tabs').tabs({
    cookie: {name: 'myTabCookie', expires: 1}, 
    spinner: '<img src="img/icons/loading.gif" />', 
    load: function (e, ui) { $(ui.panel).find('.tab-loading').remove(); }, 
    select: function (e, ui) { 
      var $panel = $(ui.panel); 
      if ($panel.is(':empty')) { 
        $panel.append('<div class="tab-loading" style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold; width: 100%">Loading...</div>') 
      } 
    } 
  }) 
});
```